Controlling a Bluetooth app over the internet
I have a robot mower and it's great, however, if it gets stuck, it can only be controlled via Bluetooth using its Android app, which is not much use if I'm away from home.
Is there a way to control a spare phone mounted on the robot that has the app on it from my own phone over the internet?

Have you tried apps like TeamViewer or AnyDesk that allow to remote control the phone?

Many thanks for the reply.Yes, I have tried 4 or 5 different ones, unfortunately, my Internet is really quite slow as I live in a semi rural area.

Is there such a thing as a pair of devices that can just relay my Bluetooth commands

That is not possible because apps can not read or modify Bluetooth commands/packets sent by other apps. Therefore you can not forward it to a second device.
